# Errors importing 16-bit TIFF in Pillow 7.1.2

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff, 16-bit

I recently updated Pillow from version 6.1.2 to version 7.1.2 and tried to load a 16-bit tiff image, which I mainly work with on a daily basis. Prior to the update, I could load these images fine, but now it raises an error:

```
q = Image.open(file)

q
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\martinkenny\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tftwoenv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 345, in __call__
    return method()

  File "C:\Users\martinkenny\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tftwoenv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 671, in _repr_png_
    self.save(b, "PNG")

  File "C:\Users\martinkenny\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tftwoenv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2100, in save
    self._ensure_mutable()

  File "C:\Users\martinkenny\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tftwoenv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 617, in _ensure_mutable
    self._copy()

  File "C:\Users\martinkenny\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tftwoenv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 610, in _copy
    self.load()

  File "C:\Users\martinkenny\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tftwoenv\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1070, in load
    return self._load_libtiff()

  File "C:\Users\martinkenny\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\tftwoenv\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1182, in _load_libtiff
    raise OSError(err)

OSError: -2

Out[21]: <PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=I;16 size=1024x1024 at 0x180FD99E438>
```

From looking at other answers, I see that Pillow has had issues with 16-bit images before but I thought they had been resolved. Is there a way to work around this error and access the image data? Or do I need to downgrade to my previous version?

Comment: Could be https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4237.